# Change the words in some places using sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I got a format (input):

```
95.56.00.000 root pass|220 smtp1.auchan.hu
```

I want to get (output):

```
root@auchan.hu,root,pass,95.56.00.000:465
```

IP can be anything, also the domain can be anything (including subdomain), but login and password in our company is the same. Also, as you can see, I'll add a port 465 in the output result.

I was trying do it with sed and awk.

Comment: Please show what you tried, along with any errors, and explain why your approach didn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'[ |]' -v OFS=',' '{sub(/[^.]+./,"",$5); print $2"@"$5, $2, $3, $1":465"}' <<<'95.56.00.000 root pass|220 smtp1.auchan.hu'
root@auchan.hu,root,pass,95.56.00.000:465
```

Comment: `sub(/[^.]+./,$2"@",$5); print $5...` will be shorter.

Comment: Yes but that would fail if $2 contains a backreference metacharacter like `&` so using input data in the replacement string of a substitution is best avoided unless you're REALLY sure of what you're doing and have complete control over the input data.

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
awk -F'[ |]|smtp[0-9]*\\.' '{printf "%s@%s,%s,%s,%s:465\n",$2,$NF,$2,$3,$1}'
```

Comment: your result is smtp1.auchan.hu,root,pass,95.56.00.000:465 i want root

Comment: when i try your awk i get smtp1.auchan and Artem wan't an output root@auchan.

Comment: There's nothing GNU awk specific about that script, it'll work in any awk.

Comment: @EdMorton: really? I believed that using a pattern as field separator was a gnu specific feature. Good news, happy to know it.

Comment: No using a regexp as a field separator has been part of awk since day 1. Using a regexp as a record separator is what's gawk-specific.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ split($4, d, "."); 
       split($3, p, "|"); 
       print $2 "@" d[2] "." d[3] "," $2 "," p[1] "," $1 ":465" }'
```

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

```
$ sed -E 's/^([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^|]*)[^ ]* [^.]*\.(.*)/\2@\4,\2,\3,\1:465/' <<< '95.56.00.000 root pass|220 smtp1.auchan.hu'
root@auchan.hu,root,pass,95.56.00.000:465
```

This uses a single substitution command with four capture groups, assuming spaces between the words in the input:

```
^([^ ]*) # 1 (captured): non-spaces anchored at start of line
([^ ]*)  # 2 (captured): next group of non-spaces
([^|]*)  # 3 (captured): group of non-pipes
[^ ]*    # a (not captured): group of non-spaces
[^.]*\.  # b (not captured): non-periods followed by one period
(.*)     # 4 (captured): rest of line
```

So the input line is split up into these groups as follows:

```
95.56.00.000 root pass|220 smtp1.auchan.hu
<----1-----> <2-> <3-><a-> <-b--><---6--->
```

and then rearranged in the second part of the substitution command, adding the `@`, commas and the port.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed` command to remove the unnecessary items, and deploy `awk` to print the value according to the order you'd like.

```
echo "95.56.00.000 root pass|220 smtp1.auchan.hu" | sed 's/smtp1.//g' | sed 's/|/\ /g' | awk '{print $2"@"$5","$2","$3","$1":456"}'
```